# How does the Drift scoring work?

Tags: grid-autosport

I have noticed that if you make a mistake during your drift events, such as spinning, off-track or collision your sector turns red. What does this mean? Will this score still be added to your points total?

Also, what do the stars represent? Is this the quality of the drift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a mistake, your drift points stop adding up. It means you end that sector with the points you made before the collision/off-road/spin, after that point, it stops counting.
And yes, the stars represent the overall drift quality.